# How can i generate random numbers with rand()?

Tags: c, random, srand

I need help with this code I have written. The problem is that I want it to generate random numbers from 1000 to 9999. But if you run it, it returns numbers higher than 9999. I have read some forums about the correct way to use `rand()` but am still stuck.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(void)
{

    int w = 0;
    int mi;
    int i;
    srand(time(0));
    for(i=0;i<=20;i++)
    {
    mi= rand() % 9999+1000;    
    printf("%d\n",mi);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower` is one way, although it can be biased stastically particularly if `RAND_MAX` is small. There's probably a good duplicate for this although some of the earlier answers on this kind of topic are poor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want numbers from 1000 to 9999, that means you want values from a range of 9000 numbers.  So that value needs to be your modulus, not 9999.

```
mi = rand() % 9000 + 1000;
```